# How to parse the dateformat in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java

`EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss t yyyy`

While parsing this date format , i had

```
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 't'
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:845)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:659)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:585)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:560)
        at centina.sa.client.session.User.getUserDateTimeFormat(User.java:290)
        at centina.sa.client.session.User.getUserDateTimeFormatPattern(User.java:284)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
        at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
```

In order to avoid this, i would like to parse the format before, if it is valid i would like to use the same 
or else some defualt pattern

```
 public SimpleDateFormat testFormat( )
    {
    String format = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss t yyyy";
     String default_format = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
    if(format is valid)
    {
     return format;
    }
    else
    {
     return default_format;
    }
    }

    SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = testFormat();
    public void testDate(DATE_FORMAT)
    {
     String date = DATE_FORMAT.format("some date");
    }
```

How to test if the format is valid, I will be formatting the date in another method, so in this method i would like to parse the format

Comment: You can never parse a date with the first format, because the Pattern is invalid. There is no `t` in pattern description

Answer (score 2):

You can try it in this way. If your date `String` unable to parse with given format will `throw` a `ParseException`, Then catch the `ParseException` and try with other format.

```
String format = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss t yyyy";  
String default_format = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
Date date=null;
try{
 date=new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse("some day"); 
}catch (ParseException|IllegalArgumentException e){
  try {
   date=new SimpleDateFormat(default_format).parse("some day");
  } catch (ParseException|IllegalArgumentException e1) {
        // Invalid date format 
  }     
}
```

But you should use correct date format else you will get `IllegalArgumentException` because the pattern is wrong.

You can validate the date format too. just catch `IllegalArgumentException` there too.

You can find all about date formatters from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat(format).` throws a `IllegalArgumentException` because the pattern is wrong. Not a `ParseException`

Answer (score 1):

While creating SimpleDateFormat Object, just catch the IllegalArgumentException:-

```
 private SimpleDateFormat getValidDateFormatObject(String format){
    final String DEFAULT_FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=null;
    try{
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    }
    catch( IllegalArgumentException excep){
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DEFAULT_FORMAT);
    }
    return sdf;
}
```

This method will return a valid DateFormat object, in case the format is incorrect, it will return DateFormat object with default format.

Answer (score 1):

1st Pattern used `'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss t yyyy'` is in invalid format.
It can be `'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 't' yyyy'`.

If you want to include custom characters or strings you have to enclose them in single quotes. Unless you put such characters with single quotes surrounded, then it would be an illegal date format, hence not supported and cause an exception.

Examples as suggested in [**`SimpelDateFormat`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Documentation

```
+----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|  # | Date and Time Pattern          | Result                               |
+----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | "yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z" | 2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT        |
|  2 | "EEE, MMM d, ''yy"             | Wed, Jul 4, '01                      |
|  3 | "h:mm a"                       | 12:08 PM                             |
|  4 | "hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz"        | 12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time |
|  5 | "K:mm a, z"                    | 0:08 PM, PDT                         |
|  6 | "yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa" | 02001.July.04 AD 12:08 PM            |
|  7 | "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"   | Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700       |
|  8 | "yyMMddHHmmssZ"                | 010704120856-0700                    |
|  9 | "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"   | 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700         |
| 10 | "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" | 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00        |
| 11 | "YYYY-'W'ww-u"                 | 2001-W27-3                           |
+----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Examples explain that if you want `'t'` as part of the formatted date, you have to include it int the format string within single quotes.

Same rule applies for all such *custom* characters or strings like `'at' HH 'hours'`, etc. You can observe the same in examples 1, 2, 4, 9, 10, and 11 above.